# Can I say "Likewise" when I order food?

Tags: word-usage

Let's say I'm in a restaurant. My friend ordered something and I want to order the same thing.

e.g.
Server: How do you like your steak done?
Friend: Um..I'd like my steak...Medium well, please.
Me:______.

Can I say "Likewise" in this situation?, if I don't want to repeat the same sentence?

Comment: That's what the word means. From [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/likewise): "**3** : similarly so with me // answered '*likewise*' to 'Pleased to meet you' "

Answer (score 2):

If your friend gives the waiter an order, and you say likewise when the waiter gets to you, I think that it would sound natural.

Most times the waiter will understand, but I suggest using a more clear sentence that you could use to be more specific, like
"I'll have what he/she's having."

If you want to use likewise, that's okay too, but I personally would just say "I'll have what (person) is having."

(In your situation, if you said likewise, the waiter may or may not ask for clarification; I think the best bet is just to go out and experiment yourself!)

Comment: Thank you sooo much for your detailed explanation!

Comment: Or you could say "I'll have the same"